# How can I rotate box-shadow?

Tags: html, css

How can I rotate box-shadow?

I have this currently:

```css
#gradients {
  width: 52px;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background: #22b14c;
  box-shadow: #b5e61d 52px 0px 0px 0px, 
              #fff200 104px 0px 0px 0px, 
              #ffc90e 156px 0px 0px 0px, 
              #ff7f27 208px 0px 0px 0px, 
              #ed1c24 260px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gradients"></div>
```

But my desired output is to have this rotated at **90** degrees.

Comment: transform: rotate(90deg);?

Comment: Are you asking how to rotate _just_ the shadow, leaving the element in its original position? You should revise to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `transform` property and using `rotate(90deg)`

```css
#gradients {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 52px;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  background: #22b14c;
  box-shadow: #b5e61d 52px 0px 0px 0px, #fff200 104px 0px 0px 0px, #ffc90e 156px 0px 0px 0px, #ff7f27 208px 0px 0px 0px, #ed1c24 260px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gradients"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `transform` property with value `rotate(90deg)`.

```css
#gradients {
    width: 52px;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    background: #22b14c;
    box-shadow: #b5e61d 52px 0px 0px 0px, 
        #fff200 104px 0px 0px 0px, 
        #ffc90e 156px 0px 0px 0px, 
        #ff7f27 208px 0px 0px 0px, 
        #ed1c24 260px 0px 0px 0px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="gradients"></div>
```